# Is the dimming of a phone screen under bright sunlight an example of destructive interference of visible light?

Tags: optics

I have heard things like polarized phone screens being attributed to this effect but this wouldn't explain this phenomenon for non polarized phone screens under bright sunlight. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not the screen that is dimming, it is your eye that is reducing the amount of light getting to the retina.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is just because difference between white pixels and black pixels is overwhelmed by the sunlight that affects all pixels equally, and your eye can't tell the difference between white pixels and black pixels any more.

Interference of light waves (whether constructive or destructive) is not experienced in everyday life. Perhaps the simplest way is to shine a laser at a wall (or other surface) and observe a speckle pattern, or at a CD and observe diffraction.